# UX designers, what does your design handoff to dev process look like?

Tags: user-centered-design, lean-ux, product-design, agile

I'm a product designer, UX/UI (whatever else you wanna call it).

I work closely with devs during the pre-deployment phases. Because of the speed at which we operate, and the complexity of the product flow permutations, there are lots of edge cases to catch during development. 70%-ish of the time, we (design/dev) catch these missed flows or logic ad hoc.

Does anyone have a workflow that works and if so, share? Much thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a workflow that is guaranteed to work, because it will depend on the product, people and process (and to an extent the tools) used as to what would be the optimal workflow when it comes to efficiency.

So I would suggest you try to weigh up the product (i.e. what is being delivered), people (what are they comfortable with in terms of communication and processes) and process (sign-off and handover procedures and tools) to see where the bottlenecks and confusions lie before making the decision on a workflow.

Different teams require slightly different approaches, but lean and agile are philosophies and not prescribed methods of doing work, and there is room to adjust so that it can be tailored to specific team needs.

Answer (score 3):

I think it's partially inherent to working 'lean'. You design the product flow tension-based & when you catch these missed flows, you fix it ad hoc / improve it.

I think, over time, your accumulated experience will guide you towards a more complete handoff, with all flows, error states, etc. included. Maybe a solution would be to start working on a handoff-checklist, in which you include all your learnings over time during handoffs of different types of projects / pages / flows.

Comment: Great points Rick, I think you're on point to say that experience will provide guidance towards a more complete handoff. That said, I can't help but think there has to be a better way to complement the 'lean' nature of the handoff. The checklist is a great start, what comes after (whiteboarding, documentation, screen annotations, JIRA, Invision, Zeplin etc.), is still quite inefficient.

Comment: I agree that the process after is still inefficient. At the moment of handoff I still always check with the dev's if they have everything they need & still miss those edge cases every now and then ;)